# How to make a flexbox in a div to have 2 columns with ngFor of mat-chips/angular material2?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I have a list of fruits with 10 entries. I want to make it so that the fruit name text (next to a mat-chip) are displayed in two columns with 5 in each column. The chips I am using are here: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api

My CSS:

```
.flexp {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flexc {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
       <div class="flexp" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
              <div class="flexc">
                <mat-chip>
                  {{fruit.typeOfFruit}}
                </mat-chip>
                {{fruit.name}}
              </div>
          </div>
```

How can I do this? Right now my flexbox is going from top to bottom.

I want to make to so that it looks like a table, but without having to create the structure. If there was a way for the ngFor to be smart enough to make it display in this way... that is what I am looking for:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Fruit 1</td><td>Fruit 6</td>
<td>Fruit 2</td><td>Fruit 7</td>
<td>Fruit 3</td><td>Fruit 8</td>
<td>Fruit 4</td><td>Fruit 9</td>
<td>Fruit 5</td><td>Fruit 10</td></tr>
</table>
```

If it is not possible, please state.

Comment: Let's assume one of your clients repeats a row 12 times. And each row contains 1 column. And each column contains the item they actually want to repeat. What would you tell your client?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I want it to look like a table without coding a table.

Comment: `flexbox` is supposed to make multiple children of one flex parent follow some alignment and distribution rules. Instead of having 12 children inside one parent, you have 12 parents, each with 1 children. You either apply flex to the parent of the parents or you apply your `*ngFor` to `.flexc`. I'd personally throw `.flexc` away (if you coded it for this case only) and simply repeat `<mat-chip>`s.

Comment: So the problem with my question is the mat-chip I want to display side by side with the fruit.name... when putting *ngFor on the mat-chip it looks funny

Comment: I believe `style="display: inline-block;"` is overriding `display: flex;` in `.flexp`. So you think you are using flexbox but you are not.

Comment: Can you show how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Your 'table example only display one row, with 10 columns.. it's not really what you want, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatGridList` is provided for this very reason.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="48px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
        <div class="flexc">
            <mat-chip>
                {{fruit.typeOfFruit}}
            </mat-chip>
            {{fruit.name}}
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

See [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5fybg?embed=1&file=app/fruit-chips-grid-example.css).

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that the table code you gave as an example is wrong, since you mentionned that you want 2 columns with 5 rows, which is equivalent to this. The answer below is to have a display similar to the table here

```
<table>
<tr><td>Fruit 1</td><td>Fruit 6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fruit 2</td><td>Fruit 7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fruit 3</td><td>Fruit 8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fruit 4</td><td>Fruit 9</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fruit 5</td><td>Fruit 10</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you want to use flex, you need to set `flow-direction` to `column` and have a max-height on the container, equal to 5 times the height of a *row*

**scss**

```
$rowHeight: 40px;
.flexp {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: calc(5 * #{$rowHeight});
}

.flexc {
    height: $rowHeight;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <div class="flexp">
     <div class="flexc" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">

        <mat-chip>
          {{fruit.typeOfFruit}}
        </mat-chip>
        {{fruit.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**Other solution not using flex**

You can use the [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property

**scss**

```
$rowHeight: 40px;
.fruitContainer {
    column-count: 2;
    max-height: calc(5 * #{$rowHeight});
}

.fruit {
    height: $rowHeight;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <div class="fruitContainer">
     <div class="fruit" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
        <mat-chip>
            {{fruit.typeOfFruit}}
                    </mat-chip>
                    {{fruit.name}}
    </div>

</div>
</mat-chip-list>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-pgidww?file=app/app.component.ts)

Below is the result

[image: illustration]

Comment: I like the true flexbox and detail of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `columns` to define adaptive column layouts within a containing element.  For example...

```
#container {
    -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
    -moz-columns: 2 200px;
    columns: 2 200px;
}
```

The first value (2) declares the number of columns and the second value (200px) declares their minimum width, such that the browser will collapse the columns if the container isn't wide enough.  Vendor prefixing might not be strictly necessary but is still recommended.

See this [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) post, which also deals with column gutters etc, for more info.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Changing your CSS to this will wrap it as you like, but not in that order. The direction is ltr.

```
.flexp {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexc {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way also..

CSS

```
  .flexp {
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 200px;
   width: 300px;
   }

  .flexc {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 160px;
   text-align: left;
   border: 1px solid white;
   }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="flexp">
   <div class="flexc" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
      <mat-chip>
        {{fruit}}
      </mat-chip>
   </div>
 </div>
```